# c# - hiding a connection in a .dll

Tags: c#, encryption, dll, dotpeek

I'm new to c#, but I need to change an existing program, by merely changing the connection string. The idea is to redirect the connection to a test database environment. I've found that the code uses a dll to create a connection to the server. I used Jetbrains Dotpeek to look inside the dll, but I could only see methods and functions, but nowhere could I see the connection detail to change it.

**What ways are there of encrypting a connection string? Are there special files used generally for this, that I can look for?**

To give more elaborate information:

In the normal code in the cs file, there is for example this:

```
var result = new LibSqlQuery(Db.ABC.ConnectionString, sql);
return result;
```

and Db is a method in a dll defined as following:

```
public static class Db
{
    private static Dictionary<string, LibDbConnection> _connections = new Dictionary<string, LibDbConnection>();

    private static LibDbConnection GetConnection(string connectionName)
    {
      lock (Db._connections)
      {
        if (!Db._connections.ContainsKey(connectionName))
          Db._connections.Add(connectionName, new LibDbConnection(connectionName));
      }
      return Db._connections[connectionName];
    }

    public static LibDbConnection ABC => Db.GetConnection("conABC");

    public static LibDbConnection CDE => Db.GetConnection("conCDE");
}
```

where ABC and CDE are database environments.

Comment: Generally a .NET application would maintain a database connection string in a config file.

Comment: The connection string itself is (hopefully) not hardcoded. E.g, oracle stores their connections in the `tnsnames.ora` file. I assume the DLL just takes care of the connecting to a database based on the passed arguments. What database are you using?

Comment: We're using SQL-Server.

Comment: In a corporate enviroment, where SQL Server integrated security can be used, encrypting connection strings points to poor user management. If you are under a domain, you can create windows security groups (domain groups) and grant the login to those groups in the SQL Server. So no password would be in the connection string and no need to encryption. Plus an easy way to manage access to applications (just  add/remove users to the group)

Answer (score 0):

I found another config file, which had the connections. This can be closed now. Thank you.